# ¿cuál de todos los archivos .css se utiliza para estilos con bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap

Dentro de la carpeta CSS de Bootstrap hay seis archivos .css y otros seis .map de los cuales no comprendo la finalidad de tantos, puedo deducir que 'segun el uso' que vaya a hacer de ellos en el diseño, sin embargo sigo sin entender el uso para cada uno, los debo invocar en los archivos que se dedique a cada caso: por ejemplo: bootstrap-grid.css para la ubicacion global
bootstrap-grid.min.css  bootstrap-reboot.css cuando hayan errores? ¿y asi cada una?

Comment: que tal si usas el CDN de bootstrap ?

Comment: bien, pero sabes de algo en español ?¿

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo a la documentación de boostrap, que puedes encontrar aquí [boostrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/contents/#css-files)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivos boostrap.css y bootstrap.min.css**

---

Como puedes observar los 2 primeros tanto la versión normal con un mayor peso, como la versión `min` incluyen componentes, content, el layout y utilidades(este es el mas común de uso)

> La versión minificada al tener un menor peso es la que usualmente se utiliza para desarrollos en producción

Entiéndase por componentes que incluye el uso de:

- Cards
- Buttons
- Carrousel
- Dropdows
- Forms
- Inputs
- Modals
  etc

  Entonces si no ocupas resetear valores ni tampoco usar el sistema de grids que ofrece, bastará con que elijas alguno de los primeros de la lista. recordemos que el que tiene en su nombre el `.min` es aquel que esta optimizado para su carga en cada petición; pues aspectos como la identación y los espacios entre renglones se quitan

**Archivos .grid.css y .grid.min.css**

---

Los siguientes 2 archivos estan pensados en ofrecer mayormente un sistema de grid, basado en el uso de *contenedores, filas y columnas* para poder acomodar el contenido su construcción esta basada en la implementación de **flexbox** pero deacuerdo a la misma tabla mostrada mas arriba puedes ver que carece de otros elementos

**Archivos .reboot y .reboot.min.css**

---

El último par que son de `reboot` nos sirven para resetear valores de elementos específicos

Tomado de la propia documentación

Here are our guidelines and reasons for choosing what to override in Reboot:

> Update some browser default values to use rems instead of ems for
>   scalable component spacing. Avoid margin-top. Vertical margins can
>   collapse, yielding unexpected results. More importantly though, a
>   single direction of margin is a simpler mental model. For easier
>   scaling across device sizes, block elements should use rems for
>   margins. Keep declarations of font-related properties to a minimum,
>   using inherit whenever possible.

**Traducción**

Aquí están nuestras pautas y razones:

1. Actualice algunos valores predeterminados del navegador para usar rems en lugar de ems para el espaciado de componentes escalable.
2. Evitar el margen superior. Los márgenes verticales pueden colapsar, dando resultados inesperados. Sin embargo, lo más importante es que una sola dirección de margen es un modelo mental más simple.
3. Para facilitar el escalado de tamaños de dispositivos, los elementos de bloque deben usar rems para márgenes.
4. Mantenga las declaraciones de propiedades relacionadas con la fuente a un mínimo, utilizando heredar siempre que sea posible.